# If x is positive, how can the output of x % 101 be zero?

Tags: java

I wrote this program after asking lots of questions and in my way to test the program, I put 2 strange names and I get different result ... if you give these names "salman" then "sania" it gives the result Zero !! I mean how could be possible ? 2 integer and sum them and divide them and get zero ????

So I assume my code is definitely wrong but where ?

```
package loveindex;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoveIndex {
        public static void main(String[] args) {


            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter your name :");
            String name1 = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter your Lover's name ");
            String name2 = scan.nextLine();

            name1 = name1.toUpperCase();

            char[] ascii1 = name1.toCharArray();
            int sum01 = 0;
            for (char ch : ascii1) {
                sum01 += ch;
            }



            name2 = name2.toUpperCase();
            char[] ascii2 = name2.toCharArray();
            int sum = 0;
            for (char ch : ascii2) {
                sum += ch;
            }

            int sumTot= (sum+sum01)%101;
            System.out.println("Percentage of Love    " + sumTot);

            scan.close();

}
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not clear what OP is trying to do.

Comment: why ? people even answered and I got my answer !! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obvious error as you are searching for.
You are using the modulo operator which returns the remainder of a division.

In your case the sum of your calculation using "salman" and "sania" is 808.
808 divided by 101 is 8.

As you can see there is no remainder of this operation so that the modulo operator returns 0.

***For example:***

809 divide by 101 is 8 with a remainder of 1.
The modulo operator will return 1 then.

Comment: thanks for ur comprehensive answer ...

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the ascii values of "SALMANSANIA" is 808, and 808 % 101 = 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is no division operation happening in your code, the `%` is the modulo operator which is giving you the remainder of dividing the sum by 101. If the sum is a multiple of 101 then you will get 0 returned as the result.